# Ion Auth crear usuario (no administrador) sin logearse

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Bueno pues mi duda es la siguiente, he implementado un sistema de login haciendo uso de la fantástica librería de Ion Auth, la cual trae consigo múltiples opciones, entre ellas un panel de administrador para crear administradores, grupos o usuarios no administradores dentro de esos grupos. Lo que quiero conseguir es que desde fuera del sistema de logeo me deje crear usuarios (no administradores) para que los usuarios puedan crear sus propias cuentas y entrar en la aplicación (estos usuarios no podrán tener acceso a las funciones del administrador).

El caso es que cuando intento dirigirme directamente a crear un usuario llamando a la función create_user(), me redirecciona al login sin dejarme crearlo.

**La función**

```
// create a new user
    public function create_user() {
        $this->data['title'] = $this->lang->line('create_user_heading');

        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in() || !$this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {
            redirect('auth', 'refresh');
        }

        $tables = $this->config->item('tables', 'ion_auth');
        $identity_column = $this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth');
        $this->data['identity_column'] = $identity_column;

        // validate form input
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_fname_label'), 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_lname_label'), 'required');
        if ($identity_column !== 'email') {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('identity', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_identity_label'), 'required|is_unique[' . $tables['users'] . '.' . $identity_column . ']');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_email_label'), 'required|valid_email');
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_email_label'), 'required|valid_email|is_unique[' . $tables['users'] . '.email]');
        }
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_phone_label'), 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_company_label'), 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_label'), 'required|min_length[' . $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|max_length[' . $this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|matches[password_confirm]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_confirm_label'), 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $email = strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
            $identity = ($identity_column === 'email') ? $email : $this->input->post('identity');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $additional_data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'company' => $this->input->post('company'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
            );
        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->ion_auth->register($identity, $password, $email, $additional_data)) {
            // check to see if we are creating the user
            // redirect them back to the admin page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
            redirect("auth", 'refresh');
        } else {
            // display the create user form
            // set the flash data error message if there is one
            $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));

            $this->data['first_name'] = array(
                'name' => 'first_name',
                'id' => 'first_name',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('first_name'),
            );
            $this->data['last_name'] = array(
                'name' => 'last_name',
                'id' => 'last_name',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('last_name'),
            );
            $this->data['identity'] = array(
                'name' => 'identity',
                'id' => 'identity',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('identity'),
            );
            $this->data['email'] = array(
                'name' => 'email',
                'id' => 'email',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('email'),
            );
            $this->data['company'] = array(
                'name' => 'company',
                'id' => 'company',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('company'),
            );
            $this->data['phone'] = array(
                'name' => 'phone',
                'id' => 'phone',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('phone'),
            );
            $this->data['password'] = array(
                'name' => 'password',
                'id' => 'password',
                'type' => 'password',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
            );
            $this->data['password_confirm'] = array(
                'name' => 'password_confirm',
                'id' => 'password_confirm',
                'type' => 'password',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password_confirm'),
            );

            $this->_render_page('auth/create_user', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No conozco Ion Auth pero según el código que muestras deberías de eliminar o comentar parte de la condición del if

```
if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in() /* || !$this->ion_auth->is_admin()*/ ) {
        redirect('auth', 'refresh');
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, al final, aunque me ha costado, he encontrado un tutorial explicando cómo podemos hacer lo que propongo de forma más o menos profesional. http://avenir.ro/authentication-system-with-ion-auth-and-ci3/register-users-using-ion-auth-in-codeigniter-3/

Answer (score 0):

He aquí un tutorial de cómo poder hacer registros a usuarios sin tener que pasar por el panel de administración de Ion Auth.
[Tutorial administrador + usuario con Ion Auth y Codeigniter 3](http://avenir.ro/authentication-system-with-ion-auth-and-ci3/register-users-using-ion-auth-in-codeigniter-3/)